# I made a promise with a condition but later I broke it, how to do repentance?

Tags: tawba, oaths

I made a promise to Allah that I will not consume onion for four month if my husband loves me forever but unfortunately I consume chips which made up of onion powder. I am feeling so guilty, depressed and low because I disobey Allah, I'm also afraid that if my husband left me or does not love me. Is there any solution to do repentance?